# induction for idempotent matrix : $P^n = P$

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

> Given that $P^2 = P$ how do i prove by induction that $P^n = P$?

I have tried the following:  we know that $P^k = P$ holds for $k = \{1,2\}$. If we now take $k=3$:
$$
\begin{align}
P^3 &= P^2P
\\ &=PP \tag*{($P$ is idempotent)} \\
\\&= P^2
\\&=P
\end{align}
$$
therefore $P^k = P$ holds for all natural numbers.

**however**, this seems... incomplete for me... Am I missing something?

Comment: Assume that it holds for some $n$. Then prove that it also holds for $n+1$. It is not enough to show that $P^3 = P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base case: $P^2 = P$. Given.

Induction Hypothesis: Assume $P^k = P$ for some $k > 1$.

Induction Step: We have to prove $P^{k+1} = P$

Now, $P^{k+1} = P^k P = P P = P^2 = P$, where we used induction hypothesis while going from 2nd to 3rd equality. Thus, it is proved for all $k \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $P^{n-1}=P$.
Then
$$\begin{align*}P^n&=P(P^{n-1})\\
&=PP\\
&=P^2\\
&=P.
\end{align*}
$$
We're given $P^2=P$, so by induction on $n$, we're done.

Thinking of induction as reaching back to the previous cases instead of reaching forward to the next case can be insightful.